# Docker executor in Gitlab Runner resolves database to localhost instead of alias, via Symfony's Doctrine

Tags: postgresql, symfony, docker, gitlab-ci

I have a symfony project with the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
test:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/MYIMAGEURL:latest

    variables:
        # POSTGRES - Use the values from the .env.test file.
        POSTGRES_DB: db
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: asdfasdf

        # MISC
        APP_ENV: test

    services:
        -   name: postgres:10
            # "postgresql" is what we use in the .env.test file
            alias: postgresql

    before_script:
        - cd my-project

    script:
        - cp .env.test .env
        - composer install
```

Symfony's `cache:clear --env=test` fails when doctrine tries to make a connection:

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused   
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting  
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?                                     
  could not connect to server: Address not available                    
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting        
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

My .env.test file has the following URL:

```
DATABASE_URL=pgsql://postgres:asdfasdf@postgresql:5432/db
```

So I know it should be looking for the `postgresql` host.

I further confirmed the doctrine config using `php bin/console debug:config doctrine`, and the defined default connection URL is: `url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'`. I also set and confirmed that the `cache:clear` command is being run in the `test` environment. Why is `resolve:DATABASE_URL` resolving to localhost?

I don't know what else to try. It always connects to `localhost` rather than `postgresql`. What else should I try?

EDIT: Additionally, I followed the guide on [testing a job locally](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-to-debug-a-job-locally) using manual service links and everything runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the `APP_ENV: test` config variable. The `bin/console` file had code in it that checked if this env variable is set, and only if NOT set would it load the .env files. After removing this variable dotenv loaded the .env files as desired.